# angle of rotation and axis of rotation of 3x3 matrix

Tags: geometry

\begin{pmatrix}
√ 3/2 & -1/4 & √3/4\\ 
1/2 & √3/4 & -3/4\\ 
0 & √3/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}

I have found the angle of rotation to be Cos^-1 (3√3 + 2)/8. Can anyone verify if this is correct? Also I am struggling to find the axis of rotation after getting 2 different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the formula
$${\rm trace}(A)=1+2\cos\alpha$$
gives
$$\alpha=\pm\cos^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{3\sqrt3-2}{8}\Bigr)\ .$$
The sign will depend on which direction you take for the axis.  Also **note**: I have not checked but am taking your word for it that this is a rotation matrix, if not then this answer will be meaningless.

Comment: Mathematica agrees it is a rotation matrix. In the duplicate question, there was a comment questioning this, but it seems to have originated in a typographical error that was later fixed.

Comment: That's fine, I didn't mean it wasn't a rotation matrix, just that I hadn't checked.

Comment: No problem, so I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Mathematica. Here is what it told me:

$\left(1+{2\over\sqrt{3}}, {1\over\sqrt{3}},1\right)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. So this vector spans the rotation axis.

The rotation angle does not seem to be a simple expression, and it also does not seem to be equal to what you have. It is around $\pm$ 66 degrees.